# Understanding the definition of left derived functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

I'm studying homological algebra. But I stuck in a place in Rotman's Advanced Algebra II, 3rd ed. What does $T\hat{f}$ mean in the paragraph? The point made me confused is that $T$ is a functor from $_R\textbf{Mod}$ to $_S\textbf{Mod}$, how can $T$ apply on the chain map $\hat{f}$? Is the symbol the author used problematic? And what does the $T\hat{f}$ really mean in the context?

[image]
[image]

Comment: $T$ takes $R$-modules like each $P_A$ and $P'_{A'}$ to $S$-modules like $TP_A$ and $TP'_{A'}$. The chain map $\check{f}: P_A \to P'_{A'}$. So how to denote the induced map from $TP_A \to TP'_{A'}$? $T\check{f}$ seems a natural choice (with some natural abuse of notation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an abuse of notation : $T$ induces an obvious functor from chain complexes to chain complexes, and the author is just using the same notation for the induced functor.